# suggestion in Kibana Devtools doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, devtools

I'm learning about elasticsearch and Kibana, So I'm comparing local and cloud environment.

but autocomplete suggestion doesn't work in local.

[cloud service of my firm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJLvU.png)

[local(my PC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbyYW.png)

When I use "Ctrl + space" shortcut, there isn't any suggestion in my PC.

I want to use index, API suggestions in local PC

Comment: try start the text with ".

Comment: it's not work neither....

Comment: are you using the same Kibana version? also, what happens when you type the quotes?